# Where to find stencil fonts?

Tags: papercutting

I'm looking for uncommon fonts resources to cut stencils.
They musn't have isolated parts that would be detached from the main stencil.

On google fonts, I can only find 3: https://fonts.google.com/?query=stencil

Can you guide me to a greater choice resource?

Answer (score 4):

Other resources I can suggest are these:

http://www.1001fonts.com/stenciled-fonts.html
https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/stencil-fonts.htm

Try out which suits your design best.
Check out sites that have "free" download option for flexibility.

If not free, you can redo/recreate some letters you need in Adobe Illustrator/Corel Draw, just get the letters you need.

Answer (score 3):

I like [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/). Searching for ['stencil'](http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=stencil) turns up a decent number of stencil/'Army' style fonts, many of which look like they could plausibly work as actual stencils.